# Prove $BA-A^2B^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices containing real elements and  satisfying the following conditions

$$AB-B^2A^2=I$$

$$A^3+B^3=O$$

then prove that

$$BA-A^2B^2=I$$

My Attempt:
If we are able to prove that if either of $A$ or $B$ is invertible then we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* What is
$$
\pmatrix{A&-B^2\\ B^2&A}\pmatrix{B&-A^2\\ A^2&B}?
$$

Comment: It will be $$(AB-B^2A^2)I=I^2=I$$. Brilliant.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Motivated by your thinking , I developed the line $$(A-iB^2)(B-iA^2)=I$$

Comment: @Maverick Yes, that will do the trick too.

Comment: Can you suggest any good book/resource from where more of such problems can be obtained

Comment: @Maverick Sorry, I don't know any relevant resource.